# Find JSON Schema in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, json, t-sql, jsonschema, sql-server-2016

I have JSON in a field, but I need to check it's schema before I process it. I need to know if anything has been added or removed from the schema.

Is there a way to extract the JSON schema from a JSON string so I can compare it to a known schema?

An online example is http://jsonschema.net/, but I want to do the same thing in TSQL

Comment: I am unfamiliar with any built in functionality to do this.  You will probably have to manually hack it and put the fields into a table and validate against it.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server don't support any json schema binding.

If your JSON is simple or flat, you can use

```
SELECT [key] FROM OPENJSON(@json)
```

to find all keys on the first level and compare them with some expected key set.